# How to extract data from nested json array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, multidimensional-array

Every time user submits data, I receive it in nested json array of data and I need extract that data.

So, sometimes it can be from **guestion_1** to **guestion_5** and then in another example from **guestion_1** to **guestion_9** and so on.

In this way I receive dynamic json array of data for each user submission.

Example of possible json result:

```
{ 
  question_xx: [ 'Another question?', 'Probably yes' ],
  question_3: [ 'Home origin planet?', 'Mars' ], 
  question_2: [ 'Are you from planet Earth?',   'No' ],  
  question_1: [ 'Home origin Galaxy?', 'Milky Way' ], 
}
```

I expect output to be:

Home origin Galaxy? Milky Way
Are you from planet Earth? No
Home origin planet? Mars

and so on

Comment: You can use ```Object.entries(j)```, key-value pairs will be returned as an array. You will have something like this ```[ ["question_xx", ["Another question?", "Probably yes"] ], ["question_3", "Home origin planet?", "Mars"],...]``` Then you can iterate the arrays, and do whatever you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the arrays as an array of arrays with [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/values). How you go from there depends on what specifically you're after. To get your output as strings, you can `map()` over the outer array and `join()` everything:

```js
let j = { 
    question_xx: [ 'Another question?', 'Probably yes' ],
    question_3: [ 'Home origin planet?', 'Mars' ], 
    question_2: [ 'Are you from planet Earth?',   'No' ],  
    question_1: [ 'Home origin Galaxy?', 'Milky Way' ], 
  }

// array of arrays
let arr = Object.values(j)
console.log(arr)

// join arrays as strings
// join inner arrays with space, outer arrays with new line
let strings = arr.map(arr => arr.join(" ")).join(' \n')
console.log(strings)
```